# Handle server error while using Observables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-services

i'm working on an Angular 2 Apllication where i have in my login feature this service.

```js
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { contentHeaders, apiUrl} from '../shared/headers';
@Injectable()
export class LoginService extends BaseService{
constructor(private http: Http){
super();
}
/**
* send the user login data (email, password) and the token back to be stored on the client side.
* @param user
* @returns {any|Promise}
*/
login(user: any): Observable<any>{
let body = JSON.stringify(user);
return this.http.post(apiUrl + '/login', body, { headers: contentHeaders })
.map(this.extractData)
.catch(this.handleError);
}
/**
* extract response data and return it to the component
* @param res
* @returns {*}
*/
public extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res.json();
console.log(body);
return body;
}
/**
* handle service error
* @param error
* @returns {ErrorObservable}
*/
public handleError(res: Response) {
return Observable.throw(res);
}
}
```

- and i use it in my LoginComponent in this way

```js
this.loginService.login(userObj)
.subscribe(
(response: any) => {
// success call that is Ok
},
(errorRes: any)=> {
console.log('res in err is', error);
}
```

-the result of console.log in my component is

```js
TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function
```

- i tried to search stackoverflow or in github if an issue solves this but i couldn't find soething that helps me, so if someone can help me handle the error in LoginComponent as a response from handleError method of the service and get the error message of the server in my component it will be great.
  Note: the success part is working fine the problem is in the case of error when i make
  return Observable.throw(res);
- thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to catch the error i  the login component as the error will be generated in the service right ? (errorRes: any)=> {
console.log('res in err is', error); i guess is fine to log errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `Observable.throw()`.

Add this import statement:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

Comment: thanks Man for your help :) this did the trick for me it worked when i added
`import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';`
to the above imports

Comment: @AmrMohamed consider marking the answer as solved if it worked.. so anyone else looking will know the right answer

Answer (score 0):

When ever throw is raised you should handle using catch operator as below

```
getTasks(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("data we got is " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
    private handleError(error: Response) {
            console.log(error);
                    }
```

Also you are throwing again in your error Handler method which should not be as such

```
this.loginService.login(userObj)
.subscribe(
(response: any) => {
// success call that is Ok
},
(error)=> {
////////////////////////error message is available in this object
console.log('res in err is', error);

})
```

Comment: - Not working man just gives me the same error
`res in err is TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function(…)`
- 
Note the imports part
`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`
and i use `.subscribe()` in my component is that the problem ?

Comment: Ok you don't but in my case i want to return th error from the `handleError` method in my service to the LoginComponent as the code above you are logging it to the console i need to return it to the .subscribe() method of the component.

Comment: what is the response you get when server throws error?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized
`Object {error: {message: 'invalid credentails', status: 401}}`

Comment: you will get this object in the error object in component. Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks Man for your Help i @suraj answer solved the problem, and i'm really happy that you tried to help :)